# Dark Sky API data shown in Chrome/Safari but not on Phone (Ionic 2)

Tags: api, ionic2

I've been testing to get weather data from https://api.darksky.net/. 
After research, in my provider, where I use this.http.get, my codes are as below:

```
let url = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.darksky.net/forecast/a470b5427c601724577e80b8bc4d2d03/37.8267,-122.4233'
let response = this.http.get(url).map(res => res.json());
return response;
```

It shows on Chrome/Safari, and you notice my url added something 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/'. It is successful, very very good. I show you the image: [image]

See, I have the temperature and summary. Location I use Google API that's why no mention.

Okay, real problem here. I ionic upload and I want to see it in Ionic View. Tom my very surprise, it shows no data, except the clock and the word "in". I removed https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/ it also seems useless. Still nothing. Can you guys please help me?

I really really thank you.

*No one replied me :( But it's okay, what if it is in React Native?

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP method is asynchronous. You haven't really provided an awful lot to go on here in terms of how you're actually displaying the data, but this is how I'd go about it.

```
this.http.get(url)
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data); //here's your response
        return data;
    });
```

As I said, this is asynchronous, so I'm not sure whether you know that when you return `response` above. That's why I put in the `console.log` line so that you can see that it's getting back data.

Bear in mind that darksky also has rate limits. I think it's 1000 free calls a day, and then it's into a paid tier. So if you've been bombarding their server without any payment details, then you'll get cut off.